# Converting multiple variables in SAS from 0/1 to 'Yes'/'No'

Tags: arrays, loops, sas

I'm interested in converting the following variables from 0/1 to 'Yes'/'No' in the following SAS data set using a loop:

```
Person       Variable1       Variable2       Variable3     Variable4  ... Variable36
001          0               1               0             1              0
002          1               1               0             0              0
003          0               0               1             1              1
```

Ideally I'd like to keep the same variable names. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you actually want new variables that say Yes or No? Or is a format fine? I recommend using formats since that changes the appearance of the data but not the underlying data. Keeping data as 0/1 has a lot of benefits when trying to do summary calculations such as percent of Yes/No, which is the mean of a 0/1 variable.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would to be use `proc format`.

```
proc format library=work;
    value myformat 1='Yes'
                   0='No';
run;

data want;
format variable: myformat.;
set have;
run;
```

In this scenario we're just assigning the format `myformat` to anything that begins with `variable`. The colon is a wildcard character. Just be aware that this does not change the actual value of the variables. If you run `proc contents` you will see that the variables are still numeric.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to convert them all to character you can use PROC TRANSPOSE.  When you transpose numeric variables with character variables, all are converted to character.  This will keep the variable labels too but you may need to add an IDLABEL statement for that.  This technique does not scale well.

```
data have;
   input Person:$3. Variable1-Variable5;
   retain dummy '13';
   cards;
001          0               1               0             1              0
002          1               1               0             0              0
003          0               0               1             1              1   
;;;;
   run;
proc format; value yn 0='No' 1='Yes';
   run;
proc print;
   run;
proc transpose data=have out=t1;
   by person;
   var Variable: dummy;
   format variable: yn3.;
   run;
proc transpose data=t1 out=want(drop=_name_);
   where upcase(_name_) ne 'DUMMY';
   by person;
   var col1;
   run;
proc contents varnum;
proc print;
   run;
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it looks like I lost some rows when I used this method. Is this able to deal with empty/null values?

Comment: @statsguyz Unfortunately "it looks like" is not a helpful diagnostic.  Did you run the example with missing values?

Comment: I added null values and your code retained the subjects. Not sure why I'm losing rows.

Comment: Show your code.  Do you have log messages that seem significant to this topic?

Comment: There are no log messages indicating any issues.